# How to negate a word in pure ERE regex

Tags: regex

Is it possible to `negate` a `word` in pure `ERE regex (POSIX.2 Extended Regular Expressions)` ?

its seems possible to `negate a character or class` using `^` as `[^ab]` which will negate `either` character `a` `b` but how to `negate a word` as `ab` (`and` not `either`)?

If I have a variable with the following value:

```
week="Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday"
```

Is it possible to extract all content of `week` without `Tuesday` to get a result as:

```
week="Monday|Wednesday|Thursday"
```

Regards

Comment: Are you aware of negative lookarounds?

Comment: @Yunnosch POSIX regex does not support lookarounds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I almost guessed that. But mentioning it in the question might help to get people into the focus/core of the problem. If only to avoid answers which propose them, by helpfully minded but a little "overzealous"  answereres. ;-) On the other hand, answers are not exactly piling up.... We might need a kindly phrased and well-explained "no way".

Comment: moocan Trickery might be required. Please provide many more examples of possible inputs and which of them should match and which not. (Though that might be obvious enough.) I wonder e.g. whether the days are guaranteed to be in usual order, or is "Monday, Friday, Thursday" possible? Is "Saturday, Sunday, Monday" possible? Which can be considered normal order but in a ring. How about "Monday, Monday, Thursday, Thursday, Friday" ?

Comment: @Yunnosch, days are only for the example. Yes they can be in any order and days as Saturday or Sunday can be present. They are just unique because there is only one Sunday in the week. With ERE it's seems possible to find if word exist and extract it with eg `*[T][u][e][s][d][a][y]*` but the inverse seems impossible. It's just maybe impossible.

Comment: Would the expected result for "Monday|Thursday|Sunday" be "Monday|Sunday" in a capture? Or would the expected result be that it does not match? Do you have any attempts which got close but just did not do the trick you need? In that case please show it and explain how it fails exactly.

Comment: I understand that the days are only an example and you are asking generally by the way. I just guess (with you) that it is impossible and offer ways to discuss how impossible it exactly is. And maybe provoke somebody into explaining that it IS generally possible and how... ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch, Many thanks for your help. I really appreciate. Yes in your example  "Monday|Thursday|Sunday" I expect a result as "Monday|Sunday" with negating "Thursday".

Comment: Would you accept two captures instead of one? I.e. you'd have to use the concatenation of two captures for whatever you want to do next? Something like `s/(Monday|)Thursday|(Sunday)/\1\2/`.

Comment: @Yunnosch, due to a problem with grub2 I need to use a module `regexp` https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#index-regexp which support `POSIX.2 ERE`. It's a limited environment (no sed, awk, grep) and I can test if a pattern exist with regexp `".*(monday).*"` but can't negate the pattern to get the rest. I test my patterns with grep -E and then grub console for the result. Maybe ERE does not support the negate a `word` and only `class or character` (or simply what I'm expecting). I did not find anything about this with pure ERE ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot negate a word with any regex engine.

It is only possible to match a continuous piece of text in one go. So, you cannot get  a `Monday|Wednesday|Thursday` as full match after running the string through a regex.

If you want to skip a word you usually remove it from the string. Check if your environment offers a replacing feature.

Also, sometimes, it is possible to split a string with the string to skip. Check if there is split support in your environment.